# Do I need to await an async Redux Thunk (not Promise)?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Assume this is my thunk:

```
const thunk = async (dispatch,getState) =>{ 'some dispatch and await code'}
```

So when I want to dispatch this thunk, should I use `await dispatch(thunk)` or just `dispatch(thunk)`?

From the source code of Redux-thunk and Redux, I think I should use `await dispatch(thunk)` as redux-thunk won't add that 'await' for me. But what happened if I don't use await (it just return a pending Promise), will the code inside thunk (dispatch and pull from Api etc.) still get executed?

Thanks

Comment: It will still be executed but it's not asynchronous anymore because you're not waiting for the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That highly depends if you want to do something afterwards.

If you just want to dispatch that thunk and have it go, you can just dispatch it.
Your next line of code will run immediately after the thunk started, not waiting for it to finish.

Or you can choose to `await` it, then your next line of code will only continue running after the thunk finished or failed.